# Convergence of a sequence implies convergence of the norm of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis

> If $\langle X_n \rangle$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R^n$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}X_n=A$. Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \| X_n \| = \| A \|$ .

My thought process, $\| X_i \|= (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)^{(1/2)}$ therefore be the multiplicative property of limits $x_i^2 = a_i^2$. Therefore the limit of norm of the components is equivalent to the limit of the corresponding limit of each component of the sequence.

Comment: your thought process is correct. The proof relies on the fact that element wise convergence iff convergence and the fact that norm is a continuous function of the components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x_n \to a$, then by definition $\|x_n - a\| \to 0$.  But we have the subtriangle inequality, so for every $n$ $|\|x_n \| - \|a\| | \le \|x_n - a\|$.  The result now follows by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: I've always seen this referred to as *the reverse triangle inequality.* In any event, +1.

Comment: Ahhh,so clever.

Comment: Why do you need to reference the Squeeze Theorem? Couldn't you argue that $|\|x_n \| - \|a\| | \le \|x_n - a\|$ < $\epsilon$ and then conclude the proof?